# How do I minimize this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I have an $n \times 1$ real vector $x$ and an $n \times d$ real matrix $y$.  I would like to calculate
$$ \min_{\Vert v \Vert = 1} \Vert x - yv \Vert ,$$
where $v$ comes from $\Bbb R^d$.  The intuition is that $v$ tells one how to combine the columns of $y$ to make a vector which is as close to $x$ as possible.

I've tried Lagrange multipliers and playing around with the function
$$ f(v) = \Vert x - yv \Vert^2.$$

The condition $\Vert v \Vert = 1$ is not required but may make the problem easier, not sure.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you can omit the constraint, then you have just a least squares problem. That is a standard topic in linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\|\cdot\|= 0 $ iff $\cdot=0$, so if you find $v$ such that $x-yv=0$, you have found your minimum. This can be done by means of pseudo-inverses; multiply the equation with $y^T$ to get $$ y^Tx -y^Tyv=0$$, where $y^Ty$ is a $d\times d$ matrix. Then v can be found by $$v=(y^Ty)^{-1}y^Tx$$
where v will solve your problem. This will however lose the constraint that $\|v\|=1$.

Comment: Would you recommend using the SVD to find the pseudo-inverse?

Comment: This depends on how large your system is, if it is considerable small, then yes. But since you need to compute eigenvectors, which are expensive to compute, for large systems it might be more efficient to use iterative methods.

Comment: how do you know the pseudo-inverses exists ?

Answer (score 2):

Applying Lagrange multipliers, gives us: $x$ is optimal if and only if

$$y^T(x-yv) = 0 $$  iff

$$y^Tyv=y^Tx$$
Therefore to find optimal solution you only need to solve the linear system $$Av=b$$
Where $ A=y^Ty$ and $ b=y^Tx$. Which is much easier that finding pseudo-inverses ( which even may not exist! )

If above equation has not solution then  there is no optimal solution!